# MySQL get the latest message between 2 people

Tags: mysql, messaging

```
SELECT *
FROM messages
WHERE message_id IN (SELECT MAX(message_id)
                     FROM messages
                     GROUP BY if(sender_id > receiver_id, CONCAT(sender_id, receiver_id), CONCAT(receiver_id, sender_id))
                    )
```

I have a simple messaging system where messages are 1 t 1 (no groups).
I just want to get the latest message between two users.

The above 'works' but I think I should be using the max timestamp vs message_id to get the latest.

My table is:

```
message_id (unique, auto inc),
sender_id (Primary),
receiver_id (Primary),
time_date,
content
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you not simply do this:

```
Select message_id from messages where sender = x and receiver = y having max (timestamp) group by message_id
```

Feel like even if that's not quite right you should be able to use a having clause here and eliminate the need for the sub query.

Answer (score 2):

The following is a solution using `correlated subquery`, which is different from your original query (the inner `group by` is removed.

```
SELECT *
FROM messages as m1
WHERE m1.time_date IN (SELECT MAX(time_date)
                     FROM messages as m2
                     WHERE (m1.sender_id = m2.sender_id and m1.receiver_id = m2.receiver_id) or 
                           (m1.sender_id = m2.receiver_id and m1.receiver_id = m2.sender_id)    
                    )
```

Comment: This works but it returns the latest message each user sent. I would like to get the latest message exchanged between two users.

Comment: Updated the ans. Please try if it works as you expect.